# Did any tools or method can distinguish code dependencies from tool dependencies in npm packages

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, package, babeljs

As we all know, there are many npm packages dependenced by our project. Did  any tools can distinguish code dependencies  from tool dependencies. I am really confused.

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you mean development code vs code required to run the app, These should be distinguished by `dependencies` `devDependencies` in your *package.json*.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!